# GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport returns NullPointerException

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5, web8-cu1

When we call `http://<host>:<port>/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport?Url='https://www.<host>.be'` we get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata:error xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata">
    <metadata:code>9000</metadata:code>
    <metadata:message>java.lang.NullPointerException: null<metadata:message>
</metadata:error>
```

Within the logging of the content service we get the following stacktrace:

```
2017-04-13 15:55:35,345 ERROR DynamicStorageMappingsStrategy - Malformed url:java.net.MalformedURLException: null
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.mappingsstrategy.impl.DynamicStorageMappingsStrategy.resolvePublicationMapping(DynamicStorageMappingsStrategy.java:44) ~[cd_dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.mappingsstrategy.MappingsStrategyContext.resolvePublicationMapping(MappingsStrategyContext.java:27) [cd_dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.mappingsstrategy.MappingsStrategyContext.resolvePublicationMapping(MappingsStrategyContext.java:30) [cd_dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.MappingsResolverImpl.getPublicationMappingFromUrl(MappingsResolverImpl.java:69) [cd_dynamic-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.datalayer.dynamic.DynamicContentProvider.getPublicationMappingFromUrl(DynamicContentProvider.java:39) [content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:42) [content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:20) [content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.web.content.odata.ContentServiceOperation.doOperation(ContentServiceOperation.java:36) [content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.doFunction(ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.java:63) [odata_processor-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:36) [odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29) [odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2017-04-13 15:55:35,345 ERROR ODataFunctionProcessorImpl - Unexpected exception when executing a function.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2017-04-13 15:55:35,347 ERROR ODataRendererActor - Unexpected exception during response rendering - java.lang.NullPointerException: 'null'
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Is there an extra parameter that we need to give?

The reason why we are doing this is to see why the favicon of our website is getting a *Localization not found* exception. All other assets work like a charm but our Production Live environment has a problem with the favicon (all other environments do not). Only difference being `https` (prod live) vs `http` (all the rest). When we backtrace the Localization exception we see that it goes wrong in the call above, so we want to know what it returns.

Kr,

Thomas

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you're using cd_dynamic to do publication resolution in the CIS and there's a problem in your cd_dynamic_conf.xml for the https binding? But if not - no idea :)

Comment: can you turn on DEBUG logging in Content service and see what is the URL that is causing this issue ? From the error it appears that the failure is happening due to URL not in correct format.